# PHP's MD5 and Java's MD5 data are not matches

Tags: java, php, md5

java's code:

```
    public static String encoderByMd5(String str){
    MessageDigest md5;
    String newstr = "";
    try{
        md5 = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
        try{
            newstr=encoder.encode(md5.digest(str.getBytes("utf-8")));
            newstr = newstr.replaceAll("=", "");
        }catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return newstr;
}
```

php's code:

```
function javaMd5($str){
    $str = md5($str);
    $str = base64_encode($str);
    $str = str_replace("=","",$str);
    return $str;
}
```

How can I make PHP encrypted data the same as Java encrypted data? Please help me!

Comment: This should help :) 
http://web.archive.org/web/20140209230440/http://www.sergiy.ca/how-to-make-java-md5-and-sha-1-hashes-compatible-with-php-or-mysql/

Comment: Can you supply sample output?

Comment: I've searched for BASE64Encoder and couldn't find anything. Also if you remove `=` from the base64 encoded string you probably won't be able to decode it afterwards.

Comment: I do not need to decode, only used to encrypt

Comment: Use `md5($str,true)` to get a raw MD5 since that's what Java will get as well

Comment: thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think these are 2 methods md5.digest(str.getBytes("utf-8")) and md5($str)...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public static String encoderByMd5(String str){
    MessageDigest md5;
    String newstr = "";
    try{
        md5 = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
        try{
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            for (byte b: md5.digest(str.getBytes("utf-8"))) {
                builder.append(String.format("%02X", b & 0xff));
            }

            newstr = encoder.encode(builder.toString().getBytes());
            newstr = newstr.replaceAll("=", "");
        }catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return newstr.toUpperCase();
}
```